# installing stack ccny_vision

Tags: ros, installation, ccny-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
i can't install the stack [ccny_vision](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ccny_vision#Installing). i'm following the instruction, but i have some errors when i run

> rosmake ccny_vision --rosdep-install.

i solved the first one with:

> Run the following commands to remove
> the offending line:
>
> roscd ccny_vision sed -i '/ubuntu:
> libglut3-dev/d' rosdep.yamllibglut3-dev/d' rosdep.yaml
>
> libglut3-dev/d' rosdep.yaml

but when i build the ccny_vision stack:

rosmake/rosmake_output-20111206-162013

rosmake/rosmake_output-20111206-162013> mkdir -p build   mkdir: impossibile

> creare la directory "build": Permesso
> negato   make:
> [build/artoolkit/unpacked] Errore 1
> (ignorato)   if [ ! -f
> ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz.md5sum ];
> then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum
> file ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz.md5sum"
> && false; fi   `rospack find rosbuild`/bin/download_checkmd5.py
> https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz
> build/ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz `awk {'print $1'} ARToolKit-SVN-r311.tar.gz.md5sum`
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py",
> line 56, in 
> sys.exit(main())
> File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py",
> line 22, in main
> os.makedirs(d)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
> mkdir(name, mode)   OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'build'
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} [ rosmake ] Output from build of
> package artoolkit written to: [
> rosmake ]
> /home/mauro/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111206-162013/artoolkit/build_output.log
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< artoolkit
> [FAIL] [ 0.09 seconds ]
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_msgs [
> make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_msgs
> ROS_NOBUILD in package nav_msgs
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>>
> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<<
> diagnostic_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package
> diagnostic_msgs
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>>
> test_common_msgs [ make ]
> [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in
> package artoolkit.  [ rosmake ]
> Waiting for other threads to complete.
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<<
> test_common_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in
> package test_common_msgs
> [ rosmake ] Results:
> [ rosmake ] Built 63 packages with 1
> failures.
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to
> directory
> [ rosmake ]
> /home/mauro/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111206-162013rosmake/rosmake_output-20111206-162013
> rosmake/rosmake_output-20111206-162013

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12236/installing-stack-ccny_vision/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-06**:
where is the folder ccny_vision downloaded to... path?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2012-05-13**:
What is the solution to this problem, I am having the same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to create a directory in the /opt/ros/electric/ros/core path.

You will not have permission to create something in that place. If you still want to do it. You can change the permission of the ccny_vision folder with write access.
I suggest you to have a ros_workspace created as given in the below page

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

and use the same path for the future packages that you download and install.
In this particular case, just have this workspace created and setup the environment. Paste your ccny_vision folder there and try to execute your commands.

Hope this helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2